# A question on primitive root of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots-of-unity

Let n be a positive integer and let $\alpha$ , $\beta$ be primitive n-th roots of unity.

a) Show that $\frac{1-\alpha}{1-\beta}$ is an algebraic integer.

b) If $n\geq 6$ is divisible by at least two primes ,show that $1-\alpha$ is a unit in the ring $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$.

For a) I tried with $\alpha =\omega$ and $\beta= \omega^2$ primitive cube rots of unity and got the polynomial $x^2-x+1$. But for nth case the calculation is going tedious.Please help.
b)Here we have only to show that $\alpha $ is a nilpotent element.Then we are done.But how to show $\alpha$ is nilpotent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no answer and no hints?

Comment: For a) write $\alpha = \beta^d$ for some $d$ such that $(d,n)=1$. For b) note that a unit like $\alpha$ will never be nilpotent. For a proof of b) look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216035/why-1-zeta-unit-where-zeta-is-a-primitive-nth-and-n-divisible-by-two-pri